# CakePHP Select Query

Tags: mysql, cakephp, cakephp-model

Is there a way to select all fields from a specific table in CakePHP?
So something like:

```
$this->Model1->find('first',
                    array('fields' => 'Model2.*',
                          'conditions' => 'Model1.id = Model2.Model1_id'),
                          'contain' => array());
```

I've been looking all over the place and can't find anything on this.
I'm kind of hoping that I don't have to type out all of the fields for Model2 :(

Forgive me for my nubishness, I just started learning Cake. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't know the answer but you could also do $this->Model1->Model2->find('first'... in this specific situation.

Comment: Just to make sure, Model1->Model2 implies that Model2 has a foreign key that maps to Model1, right?

Comment: you are doing it right but you should use is the cakephp associations (hasMany, belongsTo, HABTM)then you will only have to do `$this->Model1->find('first', array('fields'=>'Model2.*')` if not you will have to do a join, strongly suggest you do it the first way :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't. The syntax you have (meaning the `Model2.*` part) will work, as will defining no fields at all. By default, they're all returned.

I don't know, though, whether the `find` call as you have it will work. It seems awkward at best to be executing a find on `Model1` in order to get data from `Model2`. As Henri mentioned in his comment, better to do the find on `Model2`.

Comment: yeah, but I would if I could. What I'm working with at the moment (someone else's code) doesn't seem to have a model for Model2 even though there is a table.

Comment: Fair enough. It's worth noting, though, that Cake will generate a model for you (implicitly) if it doesn't exist and is referenced. If the table follows the naming convention, it should work out okay.

Answer (score 1):

For some driver, wildcard won't work as expected. So you need the whole list of fields.

```
$ds = $this->Model1->getDataSource();

$this->Model1->find('first', array(
    'fields' => $ds->fields($this->Model1),
    'conditions' => 'Model1.id = Model2.Model1_id',
    'contain' => array()
));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
$this->Model1->find('first',
array(
  'fields'=>'Model2.*',

  'joins' => array(
      array(
        'table'=>'table',
        'alias'=>'Model2',
        //'type'=>'LEFT',
        'conditions'=>array(
          "Model2.model1_id = Model1.id",          
        ),
      ),
  ),

  'conditions' => array('Model1.somefields' =>'1'
  )
```

)
);